# How to match a set of tags in MySql query

Tags: mysql, search, tags

I have a table which has a column of user set tags. The tags are stored to the table in comma-separated values. ie `apples,bananas,cherries` etc.

How can I search those values using MySql and return the result in order of most matches. For example:

```
Table: users
id  tags
 1  apples
 2  apples,bananas,cherries
 3  apples,bananas,doughnuts
```

Obviously if I try:

```
my $tagquery = 'apples,bananas,doughnuts';
SELECT id FROM users WHERE tags in ("$tagquery");
```

This will only return the row that matches the entire string. I want to be able to fetch even partial matches and return them in order by most matching `DESC`. 
Is it possible to do this in one statement without looping or multiple queries? Also I would prefer not to use `FULLINDEX` as it needs to be a strict search.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Storing values as CSV is very bad database design. Read about normalization

Comment: @Jens so you think the tags should be stored in a separate database? Or assign the id to an id field in the tag database? Doesn't that create the same problem in reverse? ie. Having to then search the tag dictionary for an id among an array of attributed ids?

Comment: Not in a separate database, but in a separate table

Comment: Sorry, I meant 'table' of course. ;)